# JPanel method paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jcomponent

Can we use the `paintComponent()` method by simply instantiating the `JPanel` Object

```
//probably in this fashion
public class appletic{
  JComponent p= new JPanel();
  int d=10; 
  public void pC(Graphics g){
    p.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(40,40, d, d);
  }
//this code isn't right but just to give a brief idea about my question
```

Without extending the particular class in which that method is embedded?

```
public class appletic extends JPanel {
  int d=10; 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(40,40, d, d);
  }
```

Comment: In your first block of code, how are you going to call the pC method with a Graphics instance?

Comment: While it is possible, this is highly discouraged practice. The proper way to use JPanel and its paintComponent method is to add(...) it to a Window/Frame and let the built-in painting framework call it for you

Comment: Try to read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: The question is why?  What advantage are you getting by doing this?  Painting in Swing is more complex then just calling `paint`, the `Graphics` context needs to be setup and translated correctly so the component is painted in the right location, for example.  Painting is achieved through a chained series of methods, each performing particular jobs, so far, you've broken the paint chain responsibility in your first example.  If you want to generate a snapshot of a component, you should be using `print` or `printAll`

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"The question is why?"*  A very good question.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)  Note: This (getting a valid graphics object) is trivial with a `BufferedImage` ..